# Argumentos sys.argv[1].split() as string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Estoy atascado en un script. Os intento exponer a ver si me podeis ayudar.

defino lo siguiente antes de entrar en el loop.

```
cliente, fecha, hora, state, nombre, result, most_repeated = sys.argv[1].split()

timestamp = str(fecha)+' '+' '+str(hora)
CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 Prueba1 ALERT 4000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS
```

La ejecución es la siguiente:

```
./script.py "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"
```

Al meter espacios entre los parametros esto los toma como diferentes parametros como todos sabemos.

Quiero que:

concretamente los campos

"*nombre de la alerta que sea*" y "*192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS*"

Los tome como un único parámetro.

Lo he estado formateando con "%s" Pero cuando salgan más palabras en el nombre de la alerta no funcionará.

Comment: Zero22, entonces ¿tú recibes la cadena "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS" como tal  y no tienes posibilidad de modificarla antes de su creación? ¿Hay algún otro parámetro que pueda tener espacios además de los dos últimos?¿Cliente?

Comment: Justamente eso. No tengo posibilidad de modificarla antes de su creación, ya que los parametros vienen definidos desde otra aplicación a la que no tengo acceso al codigo.

Comment: Zero22 Es importante que confirmes si puede haber espacios en alguno de los demás parámetros (ademas de `nombre` y `most_repeated` que ya sabemos que los tienen) o si esto es imposible. A la hora de enfocar el problema es muy importante.

Comment: @FJSevilla No, no hay ningun espacio entre los otros, el unico espacio posible es entre los campos de fecha y hora. Que ya lo he corregido, haciendo una suma de los parametro.

Comment: Zero22 he creado una respuesta, no se si te vale o se me habrá escapado algo. El siguiente recurso que queda es regex si no es posible de esta forma. La verdad es que te han hecho un "favor" dándote este string, con lo fácil que es definir un separador exclusivo entre los parámetros o evitar los espacios dentro de ellos o,  mejor aún, retornar una estructura tipo json, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si como dices solo `nombre` y `most_repeated` contienen espacios y la estructura de `most_repeated` tiene como separador `" ==> "` siempre podemos abordarlo combinando `str.split` y `str.rsplit`, junto al parámetro `maxsplit`.

```
arg = "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"

cliente, fecha, hora, state, rest = arg.split(maxsplit=4)
rest = rest.rsplit(" ==>> ")
nombre, result, mr_0 = rest[0].rsplit(maxsplit=2)
most_repeated = " ==>> ".join([mr_0] + rest[1:])

print(cliente)
print(fecha)
print(hora)
print(state)
print(nombre)
print(result)
print(most_repeated)
```

Con lo que obtenemos cada parámetro como vemos en la salida:

```
CLIENTE
08-01-2018
08:44:00
1
nombre de la alerta que sea
5000
192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS
```

No creo que sea una solución muy elegante pero en realidad la estructura del string es pésima para ser parseada como argumentos. Va a funcionar sin problemas siempre que `cliente`, `fecha`, `hora`, `state` y `result` no contengan espacios dentro y que `most_repeated` sea de la forma `algo ==> algo` o una cadena sin espacios . Otra opción es usar expresiones regulares, que nos pueden dar más flexibilidad.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!, Funciono Perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te podría servir usar otro elemento distinto del espacio en blanco para separar los parametros. Me explico, usar por ejemplo el separador '**' de este modo: `sys.argv[1].split('**')` y luego que la ejecución del script sea `./script.py "CLIENTE**08-01-2018 08:44:00**1**nombre de la alerta que sea**5000**192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"`

Comment: Ya lo habia pensando, pero los parametros se reciben desde otra aplicación a la que no tengo acceso a modificar el código. Y los pasa de la manera que dije.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente para agregar la opción con expresiones regulares, seguramente se pueda mejorar.

```
import re

txt = "CLIENTE 08-01-2018 08:44:00 1 nombre de la alerta que sea 5000 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS"

pattern = "^(.*) (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{1,5}) (.*) (\d{1,5}) ((?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(?::[0-9]+)?) ==>> (?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}(?::[0-9]+)?) ==>> .*$)$"

p = re.compile(pattern)
m = p.match(txt)

if m:
  print("Matching existoso")
  print("cliente      : {0}".format(m.group(1)))
  print("fecha        : {0}".format(m.group(2)))
  print("hora         : {0}".format(m.group(3)))
  print("state        : {0}".format(m.group(4)))
  print("nombre       : {0}".format(m.group(5)))
  print("result       : {0}".format(m.group(6)))
  print("most_repeated: {0}".format(m.group(7)))
```

Salida:

```
Matching existoso
cliente      : CLIENTE
fecha        : 08-01-2018
hora         : 08:44:00
state        : 1
nombre       : nombre de la alerta que sea
result       : 5000
most_repeated: 192.168.1.113 ==>> 8.8.8.8:53 ==>> DNS
```